# I'm creating a dropdown from multiple ranges in google sheets & having a problem

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TbPKehggzCGWy6LyEuzHZc5RouBHhyju35bqIGpInhM/edit#gid=2100307022

In this sheet, I have a List 1 (colA) and List 2 (colB). I am able to merge the data from these two lists. I want to use that merged data for data validation options in col C. It needs to be dynamic as list1 and list 2 will get more names added.

You will see I have concatenated those lists in ColH. While I know I can use a list from range to incorporate the data in H, I'd really like to do this without storing the merged data in a separate column. Is this possible? Is there a formula I can write that I can directly input into the data validation form to render this data?

Comment: You need to show the problem you are having, in the question itself (i.e. it needs to make sense without the link). See [mcve]. Can you edit this so the link is helpful but not essential?